# Is there any way to write the trigger based on the approvals

Tags: apex

Can anyone tell me how to write the trigger based on the approved records?
My use case is
I want to enter the records to queue if the record is approved by appropriate user.
I need an idea for this use case

**Updated**
Get the (custom object) record details in visualforce page and submit for the manager approval.
once he approved then the record should be submitted to the queue.
My question s how to write the trigger based on the approvals(Approved,reject and pending)
In which obj approvals are stored..

Thanks in advance
​Karthick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Approvals are handled in **ProcessInstance** object. For each and every update of your record in the approval process will have an entry (record) in this object. But you **cannot** write a trigger on this **ProcessInstance** object.

Instead please follow the below steps.

1) Create a **picklist** field - **'Approval Status' (Approval_Status__c)** in your object with the values **Pending,Approved** and **Rejected**.

2) Configure your approval process: In the **initial submission action**, create a **field update on the Approval_Status__c** field to set the picklist value as **Pending**.

3) In the **final Approval** action section, **create a field update on Approval Status** field to set the value to **Approved**.

4) In the **final Rejection** action section, **create a field update on Approval Status** field to set the value to **Rejected**.

5) Now write the **Before Update trigger** on **your object** and check the value of  **Approval_Status__c**. Based on the condition of the **Approval_Status__c** field , write your logic in the trigger to assign the record to the **Queue**.